# Unable to load Meteor template, set context and bind events

Tags: node.js, templates, meteor

I am trying to render and append a template (ticket_edit) to the body. I need to set a context to the newly appended template, and the events of ticket_edit should be bound to that template.

The code:

```
Template.ticket.events = {
    'click a.edit' : function (event) {
        //when the edit button has been clicked, load template 'ticket_edit' 
        //with the current context. Please see situation 1 and 2.
    }   
}

Template.ticket_edit.events = {
     'click a.save' : function (event) {
        //this won't do anything when i have supplied a context!
    }
}
```

**So the problem is:**

-I can set the context, but then the events are not bound to the newly added template.

-If I don't set the context the events are bound properly.

But i need both the events and the context.

**Situation 1:**

```
'click a.edit' : function (event) {
    //applying a context to the template will result in events not being bound.
    $('body').append(Meteor.render(Template.ticket_edit(this)));
}
```

**Sitation 2:**

```
'click a.edit' : function (event) {
    //this way, the events will execute properly and i can save my ticket. 
    //However, no context is supplied!
    $('body').append(Meteor.render(Template.ticket_edit));
```

}

Does anybody have a good method for doing this? I'm fairly new to Meteor, so maybe you have a better method of dynamically loading templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use jQuery for this, just do it directly with the template and a `#with` block. Something like this:

```
<body>
  {{> tickets}}
</body>

<template name="tickets">
  {{#each tickets}}
    {{> ticket}}
  {{/each}}

  {{#with currentTicket}}
    {{> editTicket}}
  {{/with}}
</template>

Template.tickets.tickets = function() {
  return Tickets.find();
};

Template.tickets.currentTicket = function () {
  return Tickets.findOne({ _id: Session.get( "currentTicket" ) });
};

Template.ticket.events({
  'click a.edit' : function () {
    Session.set( "currentTicket", this._id );
  }
});
```

Because we're using a `#with` block, the `editTicket` template won't get rendered until you click the edit button (setting the `"currentTicket"` in the `Session`).

It's also possible to just do this (no `#with` block):

```
{{> editTicket currentTicket}}
```

But that causes `editTicket` to always be rendered, just without any context until the `Session` var gets set.

Note that because we're using Session, the user won't be interrupted by reloads/hot code pushes.

Comment: Perfect awnser. I'm getting to like Meteor more and more!